# Move X files from one folder to another in Powershell

Tags: windows, file, powershell

I have a folder **A** with 75000 files which are to be processed. I have 4 folders (A,B,C,D) alongside it which can process 3000 files at a time.

I want a script to take 3000 files from A and put it in B. It should then take another 3000 files and put in C, then D and finally E

Below is the code I have so far. this takes 10 files and moves them into B, but then it just sits forever without putting any files into C,D or E.

Is there a way to quit out of the EnumerateFiles section of code? I just want the first X files it finds to get moved, I don't care about how many files are in A.

Any idea?

```
$dirBase = "\\networkDir\A\"
$dirProc1 = "\\networkDir\B\"
$dirProc2 = "\\networkDir\C\"
$dirProc3 = "\\networkDir\D\"
$dirProc4 = "\\networkDir\E\"

cd $dirBase

$directoryInfo1 = Get-ChildItem $dirProc1 | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo2 = Get-ChildItem $dirProc2 | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo3 = Get-ChildItem $dirProc3 | Measure-Object
$directoryInfo4 = Get-ChildItem $dirProc4 | Measure-Object

if ($directoryInfo1.count -eq 0) {
    MoveFiles $dirBase $dirProc1
} 
if ($directoryInfo2.count -eq 0) {
    MoveFiles $dirBase $dirProc2
} 
if ($directoryInfo3.count -eq 0) {
    MoveFiles $dirBase $dirProc3
} 
if ($directoryInfo4.count -eq 0) {
    MoveFiles $dirBase $dirProc4
} 

function MoveFiles([string]$srcDir, [string]$dest)
{
    $FileLimit = 10    
    $Counter = 0

    [IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($srcDir) | Where-Object {$Counter -lt $FileLimit} | %{ 
    #Get-ChildItem $srcDir | Select-Object -first $FileLimit | %{ 

        Move-Item $_ -destination $dest
        $Counter++

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem $dirProc1 | select -first 3000
```

?

Comment: i tried this with just 10 files... it still froze for ages (due to there being 70000 files in the folder)

Comment: what about `Get-ChildItem $dirProc1 -name` ?

Comment: is this command ends up ? [IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($srcDir) ?